# Dropbox OAuth API v2 not working after migration

Tags: oauth, dropbox-api

Here's the problem. I was using OAuth 1.0 to authorize and upload files to Dropbox with my app registered.

I Followed the migration guide but facing some issues in Auth.

Here are the URLs of HTTP APIs used in V1:

`/1/oauth/request_token`
`/1/oauth/authorize`
`/1/oauth/access_token`

for authentication.

Can anyone help me with the corresponding URLs supporting DB API v2 please? (Along with the parameters...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dropbox API v1 supports both OAuth 1 and OAuth 2. Dropbox API v2 supports OAuth 2 only.

The documentation for the OAuth 2 endpoints for use with Dropbox API v2 can be found here:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#authorization

There's also an OAuth guide which may be helpful here:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/oauth-guide